# Connect to Postgres running on the Windows host from WSL2?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL DB installed on my windows machine from WSL2 however facing issues while connecting would appreciate if you can help me resolve this issue. In addition to that I have tried below options already.

1. Windows postgreSQL is running fine on port `5432`
2. Have below entry in `pg_hba.conf` file

   ```
   host     all            all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
   ```
3. Checked windows IP address for WSL2 from following command  and then Telnet , still no luck

   ```
    sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }' 
    172.19.240.1
    telnet 172.19.240.1 5432
   ```
4. Defined inbound firewall rule for port `5432` from ***Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*** Still not working
5. disabled firewall completely - same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following for it to work in my environment (Windows 11, WSL2 - Debian).

**On the Linux file system:**

- Open or create the file `~/.bash_profile`
- Add this line:
  `export WINDOWS_HOST=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -d ' ' -f 2)`

This will get the Windows Host IP Address and set it as an env variable for the distro on startup.

- Restart the distro: `wsl --shutdown` from a Windows cmd terminal and `wsl` to start it back. You can type `env` in a WSL2 terminal to make sure the env variable is there.

**On the Windows side:**

1 - In the Windows firewall, add an **Inbound Rule** for the **TCP** **port** **5432** (the exposed postgresQL port), follow those steps:

- type `wf.msc` in a cmd terminal to open the firewall
- select `Inboud rules`
- select `Port` then **next**
- select `TCP` and type `5432` in the **specific port** input then **next**
- select `Autorize connection` and go through the 2 last steps

2 - Allow incomming connections from postgresQL config:

- open the file `pg_hba.conf` located here by default `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\data\pg_hba.conf`
- replace the line under IPv4 local connections with the folling:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

Now every ip address is allowed to access your pg server, this is necessary because the IP address of your WSL distro changes at every startup.
Please consider the downsides that could imply.

At this point you should be able to access the PostgresQL server that is running on your Windows from anywhere in your WSL2 linux distribution, using the **WINDOWS_HOST** variable as the **host** of the database. For example in your javascript code you can access it via `process.env.WINDOWS_HOST`.

I'm no expert in any of what I wrote above, so please feel free to propose better solutions.